# angular 4 ngForOf

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-container

As of Angular 4 [NgFor is Deprecated](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#deprecation-notes).

I can see they have linked `NgFor` to `NgForOf`

> https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/09d9f5fe54e7108c47de61393e10712f8239d824/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L205

Also they have the [syntax for NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#syntax) which is similar to NgFor.

i.e.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
<li template="ngFor let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">...</li>
```

With `<ng-template>`:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
  <li>...</li>
</ng-template>
```

I am using **NgContainer** instead of **NgTemplate** and it still works perfectly like below which i used for **NgFor**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <option value="{{ item.key }}">
        {{ item.value }}
    </option>
</ng-container>
```

**What is the correct usage of NgForOf in NgContainer?**

I also cannot see the correct syntax usage of **NgForOf** with NgContainer in the docs.

If the question is not clear will update on request.

Comment: If you have something that works correctly, what makes you think it doesn't have the right syntax? Especially given you're using the documented syntax.

Comment: I'm confused. In the change log they said "This does not impact the use of *ngFor in your templates.". Should we be worried?

Comment: @JBNizet The docs says that NgFor is deprecated and would be removed in Angular 5 so, if it works now it is due to some codes related to NgFor is still there, which would be removed in Angular 5 and my codes will break in more than 500 place with this changes if not fixed now.

Comment: @HarryNinh Not sure about that so was curious on this asked here to be confirmed

Comment: It's deprecated because they changed the class name, not the selector.